# iOS - Alamofire v2 Basic Auth not working

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, basic-authentication, alamofire

So I'm sending a basic auth request to Bing Image Search to grab some image data, and it was working great, right until I updated to the latest version of Alamofire (1.3 -> 2.0.2), which I had to do because 1.3 wasn't even close to compatible with XCode 7.

Anyway, here is my code:

```
let credentials = ":\(Settings.bingApiKey)"
let plainText = credentials.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
let base64 = plainText!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

manager = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance
manager!.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = [
    "Authorization": "Basic \(base64)"
]

let url = NSURL(string: Settings.bingImageApi + "&Query=" + keyword + "&$top=15&$skip=" + String(skip))!

manager!
  .request(.POST, url, parameters: nil, encoding: .JSON)
  .responseJSON { request, response, result in
      ...
```

And I'm getting the error:

> FAILURE: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.} 
>   **The authorization type you provided is not supported.  Only Basic and OAuth are supported**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue while moving from Alamofire 1.x to 2.x.

One workaround I found (and that works), is to pass the headers when performing the request:

```
let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64)"]
Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: nil, encoding: .JSON, headers: headers)
```

For more information you can take a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#http-headers).

Comment: Thanks for the help! Works great

Answer (score 0):

please read here http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/
"App Transport Security (ATS) lets an app add a declaration to its Info.plist file that specifies the domains with which it needs secure communication. ATS prevents accidental disclosure, provides secure default behavior, and is easy to adopt. You should adopt ATS as soon as possible, regardless of whether you’re creating a new app or updating an existing one."

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the error is due to you not receiving valid JSON in the response. You can use `response`, `responseData` or `responseString` to help debug.

The second part of the error is due to how you are setting the header. You cannot set an `Authorization` header after the session configuration has been created. You can either create your own session configuration and your own `Manager`, or you can pass the `Authorization` header in the `request`.