# Alamofire 1.3 Authentication Header IOS 9

Tags: swift, ios9, alamofire

I am using Alamofire 1.3 with swift 1.2 and trying to set authentication header like below code.

```
Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization": authorizationToken]
```

The code is working on IOS 8 devices but not on IOS 9. Is there any other way to set authentication header that works on IOS 9.

Comment: What error do you get? Please elaborate.

Comment: I did not get any error but authentication header is not so my server through error that user is not authorized.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `headers` parameter in the actual `request`, `download` and `upload` methods. It has never been supported to do what you are doing in your code sample. Apple finally shut down the behavior entirely in iOS 9. Instead you need to use the following:

```
let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64)"]
Alamofire.request(.POST, URL, headers: headers)
```

More information can be found in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688546/ios-alamofire-v2-basic-auth-not-working/32699000#32699000) as well as in the [README](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#http-basic-authentication).

Comment: What's the error? Please provide as much detail as possible so we can help.